# Imprimir via bluetooth usando PHP no ANDROID

Tags: php, android, apache-cordova, bluetooth

Olá! Estou participando de um projeto feito em PHP, que irá rodar no ANDROID (via PhoneGap). O aplicativo fará impressão numa impressora portátil, via comunicação bluetooth. A impressora já está pareada com o tablet, mas a forma de enviar a impressão via comandos do PHP que está sendo o meu desafio. Alguém pode me dar uma dica de como posso fazer para conseguir fazer a impressão nestas condições?

Desde já muito obrigado pela atenção em ler minha questão.

Atte.,
Jorge Rosa

Comment: Quem deve trabalhar a impressão, é o phonegap/android e a impressora. Visto que o core do phonegap não possui um módulo/plugin pra isso, você precisa de uma biblioteca de terceiros para isso. Dê uma olhada nos dois plugins: [mohamed-salah](https://github.com/mohamed-salah/phonegap-print-plugin) e 
[katzer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer)

Comment: Ok, Marcelo! Muito obrigado pela dica! Vou dar uma olhada nestes plugins. Vlw! ;)

Comment: Estou enfrentando o mesmo problema que é a impressão em ANDROID - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157558/selecionar-impressora-via-php-no-android?noredirect=1#comment328965_157558. Acompanharei essa pergunta e deixei o link da minha, caso apareça resposta que solucione seu problema.